# How to access Settings.bundle values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, settings.bundle

All of the examples and references for using values from Settings.bundle are presented in Objective-C and use older code no longer in use it seems.

**Question**

How can you read a settings value from Settings.bundle in Swift?

**Example Setting (App: SomeAppForExample)**

**Current Attempt (not working

The User has gone into the 'Settings' App and accessed the settings for 'SomeAppForExample', changing the value of 'Favorite Food' to "Pizza".

**Example Task**

How can you read the value of 'Favorite Food' in Swift, and print "Pizza" to the console?

**Current Attempt (not working)**

```
    let settingVal : String? = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "someID_food");

    print(settingVal);
```

[image]

Comment: Just use `UserDefaults` in Swift 3 to read the values.

Comment: Have you read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html ? What have you tried?

Comment: yes I have, along with many others. They show me how to create but never how to access, from what I see there. See post update for more illustration, this is how I see from the Apple examples to do it (Current Attempt section) :)

Comment: Define "not working". Error? Wrong value? Be specific.

Comment: in this scenario the value displays as "Pasta" when viewed in Settings, and settingVal reports as nil.

Comment: So the user has not yet changed a value via the Settings app. You stated they had. `NSUserDefaults` won't return the default value from the settings bundle unless you call `register(defaults:)` passing in the defaults from the settings bundle.